# How do I create and retrieve Cookies in Grails 2.0?

Tags: grails, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie using Grails 2 (RC3). I am using this for a Facebook canvas app, which means that on every browser refresh, the session is lost.

I have tried using the cookies plugin, but it seems that it's not compatible with Grails 2.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of a cookie in a GSP using the [`<g:cookie>`](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Tags/cookie.html) tag

```
Hello  <g:cookie name="myCookie" />
```

You can also use this tag from a controller:

```
String name = g.cookie(name: 'myCookie')
```

You can set a cookie using the Servlet API

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("myCookie","Cookie Monster")
cookie.maxAge = 100
response.addCookie(cookie)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Is there a way to get a cookie from the request by name or do I have to get the request.getCookies() and then parse it from there?

Comment: I found the answer to this:

`def signedRequestCookie = request.cookies.find { it.name == 'signed_request' }` ... Thanks again!

Comment: The example above shows how to get a cookie by name `g.cookie(name: 'myCookie')`

Comment: Cookie Javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html, HttpServletResponse : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/stokito/grails-cookie):

```
// Inject service
def cookieService
...
// This sets a cookie with the name `username` to the value `admin`     with a expiration set to a week, defined in seconds
cookieService.setCookie('username', 'admin', 7 * 24 * 60)
cookieService.getCookie('username') // returns 'admin'
cookieService.deleteCookie('username')
```